# How to use a string as a visual basic object?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with lots of Picture boxes, is there a way to call them using a string? Something like
PctBox+str(number) would give me the name of the box on the form, so I can loop through and change them all without having a huge block of code?

Comment: Are those `Picture boxes` `Image` controls? Named as "PctBox1", "PctBox2", "PctBox3"? Is your form in Excel, or Access?

Comment: If you just want to loop through them all, then this is an "XY" problem; there are better approaches to doing that than composing a list of names and accessing them all by name.  I believe the `Controls` collection has all of the controls on the form, and you can use `OfType` or item-by-item inspection of the item type to loop over the picture boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about Microsoft Access?
If so, you can use this sample, assuming your picture box controls are named `PctBox1` - `PctBox3` for example and you place the code in a procedure in the form:

```vb
For index = 1 To 3
    MsgBox(Me.Controls("PctBox" & index).Name)
Next
```

This sample just shows up the name of the each of these controls.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I'm pretty new to programming, I'm using visual basic 2015 and a form application. I wanted to assign an image to them from an array, so all I'd need to do is know how to loop through each one and change it. I'll give that a go though, thanks :)

Comment: So you use VB.NET and not VBA? Do you use `Windows Forms`? You should edit your question regarding that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't know which I was using since it had the forms I thought it was the application one, sorry.

Comment: The principle applies here. The code gets a `Control` reference so you need to cast as type `PictureBox`, i.e. `DirectCast(Controls("PctBox" & index), PictureBox).Image = imageArray(index)`.